# how many posts can i post on user walls on facebook via app & SDK

Tags: facebook

I want to make php script using the faceook graph and [sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) to make a time-crom task that post evey 6 hours specific status on all users walls

my question is how many users can i send to them at once ?

may be 1000 or 50000 or what?

i'm using

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token'=>TOKEN,
    'message'=>'message_here',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
);
$result = $facebook->api(
    'me/links',
    'post',
    $attachment
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no official limit, but your App will get restricted very soon if you do this. Also, it is against several Facebook rules. First, because it is spammy. Second, because you are only allowed to fill the "message" field user generated text. Also, "all user walls" means that you would need the permission offline_access, which is deprecated and will be removed soon, luckily. Else, an access token is valid for only 2 hours and you can only extend it to 60 days. For each user wall, you need the user access token of that user, of course.

Comment: i can not understand, the offline_access will end? and the peoples posting these things will end?

Comment: and the 60 day acess token can do that

Comment: offline_access will stop working soon (hopefully). this is for spam reasons, no app that is not used by the user for a long time should still have access to his account or be able to post something on the users behalf.

Comment: you can extend the 2 hour valid access token to a 60 days token, so the access token is valid longer. that still does not mean you should post something on the users wall periodically. for EVERY single post on the users wall you should ask him if he wants to publish it and what exactly he will publish. or your app will get limited, blocked and your account maybe too.

Comment: there is no way to post without offline_access

Comment: how? i saw many apps "arabic" post on users walls jokes evey 6 hours and it working cool

Comment: just because people are doing it does not mean it is allowed...and of course it is possible to post without offline_access. that permission just means that the access token will not expire.

Comment: first: please don´t use caps lock. second, this is a completely different idea than "posting something every 6 hours". also, that site is about pages, scheduled posts is an official feature of facebook pages. it is meant to post one specific post as scheduled post to one facebook page. and not "one post every 6 hours to all user walls", which is 100% illegal.